# How to return data with 403 error in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When a GET request goes to the API backend at `/obj/1`

I check a custom permissions class to see if user has access, if not, a 403 is sent back.

However, I would like to attach the object ID so the user can click a button on the front-end to request access.

My current implementation is to override the `retrieve` method and "manually" check permission there.

**Simplified Permissions**

```
class CustomPerm(...):
    def has_object_permission(...):
        return request.user.is_staff
```

**Viewset**

```
class CustomViewSet(...):
    model = Model
    permission_classes = (CustomPerm, )

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=pk)

        has_perm = CustomPerm().has_object_permission(request, self, obj=obj)
        if not has_perm:
            data = { 'id': obj.id }
            return Response(data, status=403)

        return super(ModelViewSet, self).retrieve(request, pk=pk)
```

So my current method, `has_perm` returns a QuerySet of users instead of a boolean as defined in the permissions method. How come?

Is there a cleaner approach to this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class CustomPerm(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True
        raise PermissionDenied({"message":"You don't have permission to access",
                                "object_id": obj.id})
```

and you no need to override **retrieve** method

```
class CustomViewSet(...):
    model = Model
    permission_classes = (CustomPerm, )
```

Comment: In the frontend, there is a button that links to the request access page, say `/obj/1/request_access`, if I only pass obj.id in the message, I'd have to parse the message for it, can I raise PermissionDenied and pass back data (which includes obj.id)?

Comment: At the moment the json contains "message". You can add another field like "object_id": obj.id  to it

Comment: great it works! Can you tell me where you found out about this? I can't seem to find it in the docs...

Comment: @VenkateshBachu I'm receiving the response in this format `{
    "detail": "{'status_code': 401, 'message': 'You are not authenticated to make this call'}"
}`, how can I remove the detail and convert the string as json?